# lua custom terminal not having command outputs

Tags: lua

Im trying to make a terminal but im stuck on one thing. In the doer program command do. I want docom to be the output of of the loadstring. input = io.read() its a lua terminal inside my program but nothing displays any output. Here is the code that is relevant:

```
docom = loadstring(input)
print(docom)
```

How do i make the output display? Because currently its like this:

```
welcome to the terminal!
loaded
do
do:
print("hello")
function: 0x809b60
do:
```

The third and fifth line are user inputs. how do i fix this so it shows the hello string instead of the function name. i want this to be able to manage it as i have everything else in the same lua script. please help.

Comment: `assert(loadstring(input))()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `print(docom())`.

`loadstring` compile a script into a function. That's what you see `function: 0x809b60`.

`loadstring` does not run the function. Hence the call `docom()`.

You may want to add error handling by checking whether `docom` is nil and by calling `docom` via `pcall`.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have been doing lua for a while but never needed to do any terminal type stuff. I will be releasing the program on shinycreators.com sometime soon.